# get the id value before the function by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").validate();

    function validate(){
       var x= //do some code it will return #test
       alert(x);
    }
});
```

I want to the value `test or #test` how to get it
how can do that?

Comment: use `.attr()` like `.attr('id')` this will give you `test`

Comment: but your already hardcode the id as `#test` so why you need it dynamically?

Comment: Can you reword the question? It is not very clear.

Comment: Assuming by "the id value" you mean "the selector" then the answer is: **you can't** - as it might have changed:  http://api.jquery.com/selector/  "*The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set.*"

Comment: Poor programming you are not passing argument as parameter and consuming variable x in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// first, extend jquery with `validate` method
$.fn.validate = function() {
  var isValid = this.attr('id') === 'test'
  return isValid
}

    
$(document).ready(function(){    
  if ($("#test2").validate()) {
    console.log('#test is valid')
  }

  if($(".other").validate()) {
    console.log('#other is valid')  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test2">bla bla bla<div>
<div class="other" id="test">bla bla<div>
```